# How to remove period at end of first function while allowing period at end after combining function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

First I need to remove a period at the end of this function which displays a description on my wordpress theme. For example a particular description will display as........... Visit the wonderful city.

```
<?php post_description(); ?>
```

After removing period, I need to add a city at the end of first function to make it 1 sentence, such as...Visit the wonderful city of Akron.

This is the taxonomy code that displays the city

```
 <?php echo appthemes_get_custom_city($post->ID, CITY_TAX_NAME, 'name'); ?>**
```

here is entire code............

```
                        <!-- #main -->

                    </div> <!-- #head-box -->

                    <div class="box-bottom">&nbsp;</div>

                    <div class="text-box">

                    <?php appthemes_before_post_description(); ?>

                    <?php appthemes_post_description(); ?>

                    <?php post_description(); ?>

                    <?php city_edit_link(); ?>

                    <?php clpr_reset_link(); ?>

                    <?php appthemes_after_post_description(); ?> 

                  </div>
```

now I implemented this code.........

```
<?php

$content = trim(get_the_content());
if(substr($content, -4) == '</p>') {
echo substr($content, 0, -4);
echo appthemes_get_custom_city($post->ID, CITY_TAX_NAME, 'name');
echo '</p>';
}
else{
echo $content, of, " ",  appthemes_get_custom_city($post->ID, CITY_TAX_NAME, 'name');                                                          
echo '.';
} ?>
```

But it displays as......... Visit the wonderful city. of Akron.

How can I remove the period while allowing period at end of sentence.

Comment: I don't know wordpress, you might be able to edit the function itself to fix the issue, or if not, you could use a regex to remove the `.` unless it is on the end of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for "Visit the wonderful city." and truncate the period. Then use the variable, which now lacks a period, in place of whichever place that string is coming from (I don't use Wordpress).

Comment: Visit the wonderful city is created by this function  <?php appthemes_post_description(); ?> which varies.

Comment: I am not good at regex  it doesnt seem to remove the period, anyone know how to according to code I modified.